# Acumatica Purchase Receipt Return: Open PO Line Default to false

Tags: return, default, acumatica, receipt

After clicking the "Return" action on a selected item from a completed Purchase Receipt, we're trying to get the "Open PO Line" value to default to false.  Anyone know how customize this?

The field defaulting seems to be overwritten when we press the "Return" button.  We've tried several different events in the grid but none of the seem to work.

The desired result is to default the "Open PO Line" to false after a return and once the return is released the Purchase Order line associated with the return should remain completed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Research**

The AllowOpen field on POReceiptLine is a PXBool.  This means that the value must be populated via a PXDBScalar, PXFormula, etc. or via some business logic in the graph.  To see what is happening, let's look at the DAC for POReceiptLine...

```
#region AllowOpen
public abstract class allowOpen : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field<allowOpen> { }
protected Boolean? _AllowOpen;
[PXBool()]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Open PO Line", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Service, Visible = true)]
public virtual Boolean? AllowOpen
{
    get
    {
        return this._AllowOpen;
    }
    set
    {
        this._AllowOpen = value;

    }
}
#endregion
```

As you can see, there isn't any logic to this field in the DAC, so we need to turn to the graph to see how it is used.  (Even if there were logic in the DAC, we would need to see if the graph does something.  However, logic in the DAC might have been an easy override with CacheAttached - unfortunately, not in this case.)

Let's turn to POReceiptEntry where the return is handled.  We find AllowComplete and AllowOpen being set in the POReceiptLine_RowSelected event, as we would expect since it must be populated on the graph side of code having no logic in the DAC.

```
if ((row.AllowComplete == null || row.AllowOpen == null) && fromPO)
{
    POLineR source = PXSelect<POLineR,
        Where<POLineR.orderType, Equal<Required<POLineR.orderType>>,
        And<POLineR.orderNbr, Equal<Required<POLineR.orderNbr>>,
        And<POLineR.lineNbr, Equal<Required<POLineR.lineNbr>>>>>>
        .Select(this, row.POType, row.PONbr, row.POLineNbr);

// Acuminator disable once PX1047 RowChangesInEventHandlersForbiddenForArgs [Legacy, moved the exception here from PX.Objects.acuminator because the condition was changed]
row.AllowComplete = row.AllowOpen = (row.Released == true) ?
    (row.ReceiptType != POReceiptType.POReturn ? source?.Completed == true : source?.Completed != true) :
    (source?.AllowComplete ?? false);
```

The field is populated in the *row.AllowComplete = row.AllowOpen = (row.Released == true) ?...* section of code.

Subsequently, we see that the CopyFromOrigReceiptLine method sets this value to false on the "destLine" being created.

```
destLine.AllowOpen = false;
```

As that isn't "true" then we know this isn't our spot.  Continuing on, we see in **UpdatePOLineCompletedFlag** that AllowComplete and AllowOpen are being set.  This could be our spot (or one of them).

```
row.AllowComplete = row.AllowOpen = poLineCurrent.AllowComplete;
```

*Side note:  It is worth noting that this line appears twice in an if then else.  In both cases it is going to be executed, therefore it would be better coding practice to place this identical statement AFTER the if then else since both the if and else conditions will execute this same statement regardless of the if.*

This particular use appears to be pulling the value from the AllowComplete field of the PO Line being received.  *At this point, you should consider if you need to look upstream at the PO Line to see if the field there needs to be manipulated as well.   I cannot answer that for you as your business case will drive the decision.*

There also is a line in the Copy method that sets AllowComplete and AllowOpen.

```
aDest.AllowComplete = aDest.AllowOpen = (aSrc.CompletePOLine == CompletePOLineTypes.Quantity);
```

The Copy method is overloaded, and the other signature of the method sets the values to true.

```
aDest.AllowComplete = true;
aDest.AllowOpen = true;
```

Both of these cases may need customization as well, but I don't think it's the primary issue.

**Next Steps**

At this point, we see that either the field is being set in **UpdatePOLineCompletedFlag** or in methods that seem related to copying records.  You will need to investigate further if the *copy* related methods warrant a change as well.  However, I think the initial focus should be on the *UpdatePOLineCompletedFlag* method.

If we find the other points identified require customization, we likely will handle them all the same way... Override the base method/event, invoke the original method/event in our override, and then force the values to fit our business case.  Careful testing will be needed since forcibly altering these values may create unforeseen negative ripples.

**Something to try**

We want to update (or create) a graph extension for POReceiptEntry to override the UpdatePOLineCompleteFlag method.  This compiles, but it is completely untested on my part.  We need to create a delegate and specify the PXOverride attribute.  Then we want to execute the base method before we override the field(s) in question.

*Note the extra code (commented out) as a reminder that you need to be careful of methods (typically events) updating our record in the cache and needing to be located so that we don't use a stale copy of the record.  I don't think that's necessary in this case, but it seems to be somewhat obscure in code samples that I see.  Of course, that is because I'm always looking at the code repository which rarely has graph extensions overriding event handlers!*

```
#region CreateReceiptEntry Override
public delegate void UpdatePOLineCompleteFlagDelegate(POReceiptLine row, bool isDeleted, POLine aOriginLine);
[PXOverride]
public virtual void UpdatePOLineCompleteFlag(POReceiptLine row, bool isDeleted, POLine aOriginLine, UpdatePOLineCompleteFlagDelegate baseMethod)
{
    //Execute original logic
    baseMethod(row, isDeleted, aOriginLine);
    
    /* If the base method has updated the cache, then we would need to locate the updated record in the cache to proceed
     * This tends to be the case more often with event handlers, so it probably isn't needed in this case.
     * This is just for reference as a training reminder
    //If row has been updatd in the baseMethod, let's go get the updated cache values
    POReceiptLine locateRow = Base.transactions.Locate(row);
    if (locateRow != null) row = locateRow;
    */

    //Override the fields to false - need to test to see if this creates any issues with breaking existing business logic
    row.AllowComplete = row.AllowOpen = false;
}
#endregion
```

If this doesn't get you the specific answer you need, I hope it at least gives you some insight into how to hunt down "the spot" to change.  I suspect you may need to update the POLine for a complete solution as hinted above. (See the event handler *POReceiptLine_AllowOpen_FieldUpdated* for the code that leads me to that conclusion.)

Good luck with your customization, and happy coding!